# Problem with chained if-statements in Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm working on recreating The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind in Batch, and I'm currently programming the character creation, which includes determining a player's base stats by race and sex. I chained if-statements together in succession to require two conditions met by the selection for an attribute to be set. However, every time a race and sex are chosen, the second condition is always ignored, and the attribute is set as it should be if the character is male. I believe I may be making a simple mistake somewhere in here (as I often do). Here's the full code in case I made errors somewhere unexpected:

```
@echo off
:start
title Morrowind Build 6-21-19
echo Choose your character's race.
echo.
echo 1. Altmer
echo 2. Argonian
echo 3. Bosmer
echo 4. Breton
echo 5. Dunmer
echo 6. Imperial
echo 7. Khajiit
echo 8. Nord
echo 9. Orc
echo 10. Redguard
set /p p.race=
if %p.race%==1 set p.race=altmer
if %p.race%==2 set p.race=argonian
if %p.race%==3 set p.race=bosmer
if %p.race%==4 set p.race=breton
if %p.race%==5 set p.race=dunmer
if %p.race%==6 set p.race=imperial
if %p.race%==7 set p.race=khajiit
if %p.race%==8 set p.race=nord
if %p.race%==9 set p.race=orc
if %p.race%==10 set p.race=redguard
cls
echo Choose your character's gender.
echo.
echo 1. Male
echo 2. Female
choice /c 12 /n
if errorlevel 2 set p.sex=f
if errorlevel 1 set p.sex=m
if %p.race%==altmer if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=30
if %p.race%==altmer if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=30
if %p.race%==argonian if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==argonian if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==bosmer if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=30
if %p.race%==bosmer if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=30
if %p.race%==breton if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==breton if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=30
if %p.race%==dunmer if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==dunmer if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==imperial if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==imperial if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==khajiit if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==khajiit if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=30
if %p.race%==nord if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=50
if %p.race%==nord if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=50
if %p.race%==orc if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=45
if %p.race%==orc if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=45
if %p.race%==redguard if %p.sex%==m set /a p.strength=50
if %p.race%==redguard if %p.sex%==f set /a p.strength=40
if %p.race%==altmer if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=50
if %p.race%==altmer if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=50
if %p.race%==argonian if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==argonian if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=50
if %p.race%==bosmer if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==bosmer if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==breton if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=50
if %p.race%==breton if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=50
if %p.race%==dunmer if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==dunmer if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==imperial if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==imperial if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==khajiit if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==khajiit if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==nord if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=30
if %p.race%==nord if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=30
if %p.race%==orc if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=30
if %p.race%==orc if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=40
if %p.race%==redguard if %p.sex%==m set /a p.intelligence=30
if %p.race%==redguard if %p.sex%==f set /a p.intelligence=30
echo Strength: %p.strength%
echo Intelligence: %p.intelligence%
pause
goto start
```

Comment: Personally, I would change the `set /p` to `choice` too (using `0...9` or `A...J`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you've checked the value of `errorlevel` after the `chioce` command:

```
choice /c 12 /n
if errorlevel 2 set p.sex=f
if errorlevel 1 set p.sex=m
```

The condition `if errorlevel number` will be satisfied when the value of `errorlevel` is **equal to or greater than** the number. So a satisfied condition of `if errorlevel 2` will also satisfy `if errorlevel 1`

You need to exclude the subsequent conditions from evaluation by using `if...else` construct and start checking the `errorlevel` from highest to lowest values.

```
choice /c 12 /n
if errorlevel 2 (
    set p.sex=f
) else if errorlevel 1 (
    set p.sex=m
) else (
   REM user canceled the choice by pressing CTRL-C
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `if errorlevel ...` lines should be in decreasing order. `sst` already gave the reason:

> The condition if errorlevel number will be satisfied when the value of
>   errorlevel is equal to or greater than the number. So a satisfied
>   condition of if errorlevel 2 will also satisfy if errorlevel 1

Although in this special case, it's easier to just inverse that order:

```
choice /c 12 /n
if errorlevel 1 set "p.sex=m"
if errorlevel 2 set "p.sex=f"
```

When you press `1`, the first `if` is executed and the variable is set to `m`. The second one is not executed, so the variable stays `m`.
When you press `2`, the first `if` is executed and the variable is set to `m`. The second one is also executed, so the variable is changed to `f`

Note: I changed the `set` syntax to the recommended form to avoid trailing spaces (hard to spot in the code, but can cause unexpected behavior (and some headache while troubleshooting) in other parts of the code)

Another suggestion: 
For readabilty, you can substitute

```
if %p.race%==altmer if %p.sex%==m
```

with

```
if "%p.race%-%p.sex%"=="altmer-m"
```

and `set /a` can set several variables, so you can shorten your code with:

```
if "%p.race%-%p.sex%"=="altmer-m" set /a p.strength=30, p.intelligence=50
```

and - when males and females have the same properties - you can do them in one line (although there may be reasons to not do that - like keeping the possibility to change the properties later without modifying the code too much):

```
if "%p.race%"=="altmer" set /a p.strength=30, p.intelligence=50
```